# Spelling text in italian language using textblob

Tags: python, nlp, textblob

I want to do spelling for text in Italian language using textblob, but I find just the code for English language. how can do it?
this is the code for English
    from textblob import TextBlob
    text = "I am gonig to schol"
    text = TextBlob(text)
    print(text.correct())
    I am going to school

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present it appears that TextBlob has support only for English, French and German. Support for languages other than English is regarded as an *extension* and the [docs](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/extensions.html#extensions) suggest that there are no extensions for other languages yet.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you suggest another library?